# I want to go back to Raspbian Wheezy: is it possible?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

I want to use Raspbian Wheezy. Is there a place that I can still download it?

I had a backup of Wheezy, but when I tried to install it on my Raspberry Pi, I got an error message saying:

> Unable to download distribution list.

Comment: Why do you want to use Wheezy over Jessie? I highly recommend upgrading to Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to do this, it's still available here: [/raspbian/images/raspbian-2015-05-07](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2015-05-07/)

Comment: i am unable to install whezzy, 
while i start raspberry pi i am getting this line and booting is being stopped

Comment: [end kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)

Comment: Maybe make a fresh image? It also might not work with Raspberry Pis released after May last year - like the Zero and 3B.

Answer (score 1):

You can find old images at:
http://vx2-downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/

For example:
http://vx2-downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2015-05-07/2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.zip

Comment: A little more detail would be great, do you think your answer solves the problem if the links break?

Comment: [end kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)

Comment: i am getting this line and the raspberry stops booting.